# Variables not going to array

Tags: php, arrays

I got problem with array, this is my code:

```
$random_string = array();
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
$zmienna = generatePassword();
//echo $zmienna;
if (in_array($zmienna, $random_string))
$random_string[$i] = $zmienna;
}

var_dump($random_string);
```

on screen i see olny

```
array(0) { }
```

What's wrong? Becouse I'm sure that `generatePassword();` working well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code:

```
if (in_array($zmienna, $random_string)) 
    $random_string[$i] = $zmienna;
```

Will add `$zmienna` to `$random_string` if it's already in there; since it's a blank array at the start of the code, it's never going to be added, so the array will stay empty.

Do you mean:

```
if (! in_array($zmienna, $random_string)) {
```

Which will add it if it's not already there?

Answer (score 5):

This line fails.

```
if (in_array($zmienna, $random_string))
```

`$random_string` is empty so `$zmienna` will never be "in" it.

I think you might have meant to put a NOT operator in there? if it is not in the array, add it? If so:

```
if (!in_array($zmienna, $random_string))
```

Also, your array will skip some keys. You'll end up with something like

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "c"
}
```

If you don't specify an index with `$i` (just do `$random_string[] = $zmienna;`), it'll do the keys automatically, so you get

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "c"
}
```

Comment: omg, thanks, I angryon myself wright now! Of course youre wright

Answer (score 1):

In_array function always returns false In this code statement - its does not add to array, just checks. That's why he is mistake.

Comment: http://is.php.net/in_array -> "Returns TRUE if needle is found in the array, FALSE otherwise."

Comment: indeed, missed that, got it back.